# Loading Twitter in WKWebView not Supported

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to load Twitter in a `WKWebView` on my iPad Pro. But whenever I load it up in my app it says browser not supported.

[image: Error Message]

Here is what I have currently tried,

```
var wk = WKWebView()
wk.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
self.view = wk
wk.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.twitter.com")!))
```

Is there something that I am missing? Or can somebody else reproduce and maybe it is twitter's problem? Thanks

Comment: Same problem. No solution yet. Still looking

Comment: @SeanMayes Sorry I forgot to update this, but if you actually set the WKWebView's user agent to the default iPad or iPhone agent the message should disappear. For some reason WKWebView likes using an old user agent.

Comment: @NavjeevenMann what is the default ipad or iphone agent?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this fixes the problem as of Nov 2020:

`webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"`